# How make bold the text in add_text()

Tags: python, docx

I want to make my text Bold in `add_text()` in python docx creation

this is the code sample

```
section = doc.sections[0]   # Create a section
sec_header = section.header   # Create header 
header_tp = sec_header.add_paragraph()  # Add a paragraph in the header, you can add any 
header_run = header_tp.add_run()   # Add a run in the paragraph. In the run you can set the 
header_run.add_picture(logo_path, width=Inches(1.24), height=Inches(0.30))  # Add a picture
rml_header = "\t\t\t\t\t          Project completion report"
header_run.add_text(rml_header).bold=True
header_run.add_text("\n_____________________________________________________________")
header_run.font.size =  Pt(14)
```

In this code `header_run.add_text(rml_header).bold=True` is not working is there any option to bold my text without changing function `.add_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
header_run.add_text(rml_header)
header_run.bold = True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).